# Baby Rudin's exercise 2.21 b)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Exercise 2.21 in baby rudin states

> Let $A$ and $B$ be separated subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^k$, suppose $a \in A$, $b \in B$, and define:
>   $$p(t) = (1-t)a + tb$$
>   for $t \in \mathbb{R}^1$. Put $A_0 = p^{-1} (A)$, $B_0 = p^{-1} (B)$ [Thus $t \in A_0 \iff p(t) \in A$]

Then question b) asks: "prove that there exists $ t_0 \in (0,1) $  such that $ p(t_0) \notin A \cup B $.

When I look at the solutions it seems to imply that $A_0 \cup B_0 = (0,1)$ and since $A_0 \cup B_0$ is not connected ( we know that from a)) then of course there exists $t_0 \in A_0 \cup B_0$ since $A_0 \cup B_0$ is not connected. But what if $(0,1) \subset A_0$? Then it is not true. I dont see why this cannot be the case given the question. What am I missing?

Comment: It is impossible that $A_0 \cup B_0 = (0,1)$. You have $p(0) = a \in A$, thus $0 \in A_0$, similarly $1 \in B_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible let $(0,1) \subset A_0$. Then $(1-t)a+tb \in A$ for all $t \in (0,1)$. Since $b =\lim_{t \to 1} [(1-t)a+tb]$ it follows that $b \in \overline {A}$. But $b \in B$ so $b \in \overline {A} \cap B$. But $A$ and $B$ are separated so $\overline {A} \cap B$ is empty.

Comment: I dont understand how you found $b =\lim_{t \to 1} [(1-t)a+tb]$. What if you say $A_0=(-0.5, 1.5)$ ?

Comment: @EndreMoen As $t \to 1$, $(1-t)a \to (0)(a)=0$ and $tb \to (1)(b)=b$. Add these.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your proof does not work. $A_0 \cup B_0 = (0,1)$ is not true. You have $p(0) = a \in A$, thus $0 \in A_0$, similarly $1 \in B_0$.

Assume that there does not exist $t_0 \in (0,1)$  such that $p(t_0) \notin A \cup B$. This means that $p((0,1)) \subset A \cup B$, thus $p([0,1]) \subset A \cup B$ since $p(0) = a \in A, p(1) = b \in B$. We conclude $[0,1] \subset A_0 \cup B_0$, in other words $[0,1] = A'_0 \cup B'_0$ with $A'_0 = A_0 \cap [0,1]$ and $B'_0 = B_0 \cap [0,1]$. By construction $A'_0, B'_0$ are non-empty. We have $\overline{A'_0} \cap B'_0 \subset \overline{A_0} \cap B_0 = \overline{p^{-1}(A)} \cap p^{-1}(B) \subset p^{-1}(\overline{A}) \cap p^{-1}(B) = p^{-1}(\overline{A} \cap B) = p^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, i.e. $\overline{A'_0} \cap B'_0 = \emptyset$. Similarly $A'_0 \cap \overline{B'_0} = \emptyset$. Thus $A'_0, B'_0$ are separated subsets of $\mathbb R$ which means that $[0,1]$ cannot be connected, a contradiction.